# Kohana 3 -> Checking if page with (URI) exists

Tags: php, kohana-3

With Kohana 3, I would like to get to know if a page with a by the user entered URI exists.
So basically the user enters an URI, and I will say if it will give a (404) error or not.

I already tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<?php
 public function action_test_uri()
 {
    $r = Request::factory('this/uri/is/not/leading/to/a/valid/page');
    $test = $r->status;
    $test = ($test == 404) ? 'THIS PAGE DOESN\'T EXISTS' : 'THIS PAGE EXISTS';
    die($test);
 }
?>
```

Unfortunately this outputs 'THIS PAGE EXISTS'.

Is there anyone who does know the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve [all routes](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Route#all) and test if any of them [matches](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Route#matches) the URI. However, this does not tell you how the controller handles the URI. The controller might as well generate a 404, so the only sure way is to actually retrieve the page referred to by the URI.

Comment: I tryed this now: 
$uri = 'OELOELOEthis/uri/is/not/leading/to/aaduygd gfuagufgfu/valid/page';
     $routes = Route::all();
     $output = 'doesnt exist!';
     foreach($routes as $route)
     {
          if($route->matches($uri)) {
               $output = 'exists!';
          }
     }
     
     die($output);

But it still says it exists. Is the conclusion that it is impossible?

Comment: `if($route->matches($uri)) { $output = 'exists! Route: '.Route::name($route); }`